# How to refer to "last slide" of PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to assign tag for powerpoint slide 2 to the last slide. but i can't find the correct code refer to "the last slide" (Day 1 of self teaching)

Any one could help? thank you!!

```
Sub Assign_tags()

For i = 2 To 
ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Tags.Add "pname", "Pink"
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Try ActivePresentation.Slides.Count.